# Mod_Rewrite issue on shared hosting (Godaddy & Laravel 4)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, laravel

I've got an issue with `mod_rewrite` and Laravel 4 on a shared hosting.

I have renamed public to `lvrp`. The rename itself is fine, and has been tested on my localhost. However, when uploading to GoDaddy, it first just threw a 500 error. Then I found another *.htaccess* and changed it to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It might not be the best one, but at least it works. Kind of.

I can access the start page. I can not access any other page, unless I add index.php to the URI. With index.php I can access every page.

Any ideas on how to make it work without having to add index.php?

**EDIT #1:**

```
[error] [client x.x.x.x] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This is the error I get in the apache log.

Comment: Two questions: 1) the mod_rewrite is enabled on your hosting server? 2) Are you serving your web app from a root URI or under a virtual directory?

Comment: mod_rewrite is indeed enabled. My web app is in public_html/websites/domainname. It's accessible from domain.com. That domain goes straight into the domainname folder, if you get what I mean. @RubensMariuzzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, somehow I got this working by moving the project to another directory.

Apache mod_rewrite (and regular expressions) still confuse me. I have no idea why it didn't work or why it works now. At least it works the way I want it.

To others with the same problem, I found loads of examples when just searching for godaddy and problems with clean urls. I hope it can be of some help.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to make it work without having to add index.php?

It doesn't require mod_rewrite. Just add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

This will make apache automatically find and render index.html if found otherwise index.php will be shown in any sub-directory under DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm know it's old but I just have this issue today and to solve it i change

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`